# PCA fit() runtime warning (invalid value encountered in true_divide)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

This Question pertains to machine learning. 
I populate an array with the values of a greyscale image.

```
ben = io.ImageCollection('./Ben_bw.png')[0]
ben = np.array(ben)#array of all pixels
```

Now I flatten the array with:

```
ben_flat = ben.reshape((1, -1))
```

when I print   ben_flat.shape then I get a (1, 10304) array that is not non-zero

Then when I try to use PCA and fit the array:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=200)
ben_reduced = pca.fit(ben_flat)
```

When I fit the array I recieve an error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

From what I understand there is a zero divider somewhere. But I can't understand where it is or how it ends up there.

Answer (score 6):

PCA fitting is done with n samples each with an equivalent number of features. The components of each sample are compared and the ones with most variance are kept first, thus keeping the most information. ben_flat is just one sample and the algorithm has no idea how to decompose it into a lower dimension because there are not other samples to compare it with.

Comment: I see my error now. Thank you. I misunderstood what the function is supposed to do. I need to have more samples in order to find the variance between them.

Comment: Exactly! You could also keep your one image and decompose it treating each row of pixels as a sample (same thing you have now just don't flatten) for a proof of concept to make sure your algorithm works without errors.

Comment: Also there is documentation of [n_components here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) : `n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)`. So maybe this is a problem in his case for only 1 sample.

Comment: @Aberger I am facing a similar error, I want to reduce the dimension of HogDescriptor of an image which gives a feature vector of length of order 10^5,  is there a way to apply PCA to just one sample to reduce dimension?

Comment: PCA is used to find correlation in your data so it doesn't make with just one sample. Also why do you need to reduce the dimensions?

Comment: @aberger I wanted to feed the features from HOG descriptor to a feedforward NN, without PCA, the feature vector was of length 50000 or so, that's why. I have implemented a workaround by resizing image to a small size such that HOG just gives features of length around 200